# NullPointerException in DeviceManager.getHardwareProperties

Tags: android, adt, android-sdk-tools

When I updated ADT with newer version, it crashed.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.getHardwareProperties(DeviceManager.java:552)
        at com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.hasHardwarePropHashChanged(DeviceManager.java:594)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1555)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1433)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:341)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:351)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.initSdk(UpdaterData.java:252)
        at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.<init>(UpdaterData.java:120)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.SwtUpdaterData.<init>(SwtUpdaterData.java:61)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:104)
        at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:88)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:389)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:350)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:148)
        at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:114)
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove your ~/.android folder (save it somewhere else just in case), because it may be conflicting with a previous version of ADT.

Answer (score 0):

[They fixed it in ADT 22.6.2, you can take update of it to new version .](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#notes)